# CakePHP 2.1 Permission denied on cron job

Tags: cakephp, cron, cakephp-2.0

I am getting this error when I try to run a CakePHP 2.1 Shell from a cron job:

`/bin/sh: /home/[other-folders]/lib/Cake/Console/cake: Permission denied`

This is the code I've been using for almost a year with CakePHP 1.3.7 and it worked well. What could the problem be? I've checked the permissions on the `cake` file, and it is 755, just like the `cake` file I had in 1.3.7. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are all the directories in the path set to at least +x for the user executing the cron job?  If you can't at least execute the directories above `cake`, you won't be able to execute the program.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new in this world...what should I check? The permissions on each folder up to `cake`? And what permission should each one have? Everything has 755.

Comment: OK, fixed it, it was indeed a problem with the permissions. Now, the `cake` has 755 and it works fine. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

**Make sure the file path you set in cron is executable:**

```
ls -l /path/to/project/folder/file
chmod +x /path/to/project/folder/file
ls -l /path/to/project/folder/file
```

So, latest permission will be like `-rwxr-xr-x`. and things will be working for you.  , This solution not only applied to cake but any file you set in cron.

Thats it! Cheers!!